# Why is it not possible to comment on or provide answers to deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Here is an example of a question that was downvoted (unnecessarily) and quickly closed:

[Why Should Use Jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239691/why-should-use-jsf)

The question (for reference):

> Which is better design pattern whether to use **JSF framwork** or use
>   normal css,javascript,jquery for designing a web page ?
>
> If I use Jsf framework than what is the benefits.

The question is perfectly reasonably (though it does show confusion on the part of the person asking the question), and I had been in the process of composing this reasonable answer:

> These technologies are orthogonal. JSF is a server-side technology for composing servlet responses from multiple different well-defined components. HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (including jQuery) run on the client (i.e. in the user's browser) and are returned in the responses from the server. Components written in JSF will emit HTML, CSS, JavaScript that get returned to the users browser. In short, they can be used together (JSF is what one typically uses when implementing the server with J2EE).

After taking the time to compose this answer, however, I see a banner saying that the question has been deleted and no responses will be accepted. Taking the time to write an answer only to be unable to post it is extremely discouraging and makes one not want to contribute further answers. It's perfectly reasonable not to grant points for deleted questions, but could we at least make it possible to post answers, anyway?

Comment: No, deleted is deleted is deleted. A line is drawn, why the need to cross it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it was probably deleted because the poor person who asked a question based on a reasonable confusion/misunderstanding was attacked and downvoted for it. The culture on StackOverflow seems to be to leap out and attack anyone who has the slightest bit of confusion about how a technology works or what its purpose is.

Comment: Then *flag the post for undeletion*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, also, aside from not wasting the time of people who took the time to answer, anyone else who searches for and finds the deleted question (or the person originally asking the question) will get the answer they were looking for. In some cases, people delete the question not because they are no longer interested in the answer but because they don't want the downvotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I did flag the post for undeletion. I have yet to find a single case, though, where a post that has been closed or deleted gets undeleted. It is far easier to get the community to delete or close a post than to do the reverse.

Comment: Seems like you'd just be rewarding people for asking bad questions. Bad questions should ideally get no answers, but they do sometimes. Sounds like your problem is more to do with the question being closed and deleted.

Comment: @DanielKelley, the problem is that many questions are not, in fact, "bad questions". A question that is asked in good faith and that is not a duplicate shouldn't be downvoted to oblivion or closed, and yet that seems to be what's happening on StackOverflow. A lot of questions where the person asking it simply does not have much understanding or experience are wrongly being considered "bad questions". Perhaps the issue isn't "why can't we answer deleted question", but rather, what can we do to improve the culture on StackOverflow with respect to closing/downvoting questions.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: I've flagged questions that were deleted *after* answering, and a moderator did undelete those in cases where the question had a wider use.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: But if the question was receiving downvotes, then perhaps the quality of the question was such it had it coming? Try not to answer questions of dubious quality; edit the post first to fix grammar issues, for example. If there are comments questioning the validity of the question and those are wrong, address those. If a higher rep user is assisting on a post, I find that fewer downvotes come in, maybe even some upvotes, especially when edited into shape.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll try editing the question, first, next time.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: but frankly speaking, that question is **rubbish**. Of course it got downvoted.  Apart from showing no research effort, it was going to be closed as primarily opinion based. You shouldn't put effort in answering such questions in the first place.

Comment: I disagree. That question is perfectly reasonable and isn't an opinion question. The question indicated a lack of understanding regarding where a particular type of code is executed (on the client vs on the server), and for a beginner, clarifying this can be extremely helpful and is not something that one would know to research or that one could reasonably discover without significant study.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I agree with you, but this is unfortunately a minority opinion on SO.

Comment: Even if the question is completely reasonable this request just doesn't make a lot of sense. Why would you be able to answer deleted questions? The only reason I can think of is if you were turning deleted posts into a fully functioning 10k+ club. If it would be of benefit to the community, feel free to repost and self-answer it.

Comment: The question was barely readable, contained 6 grammatical or spelling errors in just two sentences, didn't ask a real question, and only got 1 downvote before being deleted by the OP. If this is your example of a question that was unfairly downvoted and closed (it wasn't even closed), I don't even know what to say.

Answer (score 7):

Because comments and answers on deleted questions won't help anyone.

If that discourages you from answering *questions that look like they might get closed* then that's Working As Designed. If it discourages you from posting answers altogether, that's unfortunate, but there should be plenty of good or at least decent questions coming in that you can answer.

Comment: There was no reason to believe that it would be closed, however. It was a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan - it was a very poor fit for Stack Overflow.