# No comments on deleted questions means no way to tell the poster they shouldn't have deleted the question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm sure most if not all of us have had the experience of posting a "dumb" question on Stack Overflow, and then wanting to delete our question as a result.  But at the same time, questions that you feel are "dumb" can be extremely helpful to others, and that's something I personally had to learn here (I didn't realize it when I first started).

When someone new to Stack Overflow deletes their question, I'd like to be able to tell them something to the effect of "you're allowed to delete your question if you want, but if it's not a duplicate of another question or off-topic for the site, it *should* be left in, because you probably won't be the last person with such a 'dumb' question (and if you delete it those people will miss out on being able to learn what you learned)".

However, I can't, because I can't comment on a deleted question.  It seems like a flaw in Stack Overflow that we have new people deleting potentially valuable questions out of embarrassment, and there's no clear way for more seasoned members to discourage that.

Comment: I mean... that sounds positive overall.

Comment: I would expect the majority of such questions to be sand. typo's, misuse of well documented methods, etc. I'm sure it'd be possible to find a pearl somewhere in the sea of self deleted questions... i'm just not convinced there's enough there to open the potential of allowing comments to continue after question deletion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not possible to comment on or provide answers to deleted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260659) and [Commenting on deleted answers, if you downvoted and can see them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315896)

Comment: I'm definitely talking about a subset of deleted posts, not all of them, or even all posts deleted by newcomers.  Newcomers certainly do delete questions legitimately.

I'm only talking about the specific case of embarrassed newcomers deleting otherwise valid questions.

Comment: As for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724143/trying-to-make-a-variable-have-a-different-value-each-refresh-of-a-setinterval/52725711?noredirect=1#comment92378599_52725711.  It might seem like a duplicate of other setInterval questions, but it was really about the OP not understanding how repeated code of any sort works, which could certainly have value for others.  And just to be clear, my stake in this isn't that my answer got deleted, it's just that I don't think this question met any of the deletion criteria, and that it was just deleted from embarrassment.

Comment: So, should we add a dialog when a user deletes their own question?, "On a scale of 1 to 10, how embarrassed are you?"

Comment: Just ask the question yourself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That suggestion made me smile, but no my goal was to be more reactive: let experienced SOers suggest to less experienced SOers "hey, we usually don't delete posts; even if they seem embarrassing that doesn't mean others won't find it useful (in fact, it often means the exact opposite)".  As for re-asking the question, the optics of an experienced member re-posting a n00b's question and getting points off it just seem bad.

Answer (score 8):

I have been in a situation like that before, and it is annoying indeed. Still, I tend to agree with [Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375183/no-comments-on-deleted-questions-means-no-way-to-tell-the-poster-they-shouldnt#comment637294_375183) on such cases apparently being too uncommon to justify opening up deleted posts for comments (and dealing with the mayhem which would likely ensue).

As things stand, I see two ways of dealing with worthy self-deleted questions:

- Undeleting it through votes. That feels awkward -- after all, it is not unreasonable to expect you should be able to get rid of your own questions if they have no answers and you consider them as unhelpful -- but it might be worth the trouble if it means bringing back an excellent question.
- Recreating the question yourself, while giving credit to the OP and possibly providing a self-answer. You can use the opportunity to polish the question, dealing with any minor flaws that might have led the OP to feel like deleting it was necessary.

Comment: [Also be suuuuuper subtle about it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332792/should-i-downvote-a-self-answer-if-it-doesnt-work-for-me)

Comment: @BoltClock I wonder what would it be like to get flags and flames for bringing a worthy question back to the library. (Thankfully, the one time I tried that my fellow tag denizens were fully supportive.)

Comment: As long as it's not your question you're reposting and you give credit where credit is due (i.e. *don't* actually be subtle about it) you should be fine. Most people take exception to deleting and reposting questions to circumvent downvotes or close votes. In my case, though, the question was originally posted by a user with a really bad habit of deleting their questions as soon as they get even the slightest hint of an answer with no consideration of the time others spend looking at them, so I decided it was best not to point fingers.

Comment: Thanks.  I think those are reasonable, but inferior suggestions.  Why not just have a link, only for members with X points, which opens up a simple prompt so they can type a message (or just use a canned one) that either A) becomes a comment, or B) is "sent" somehow to the OP?  This would allow them to *suggest* that the OP re-open their own question, without any other side effects.  I don't want to re-open the question; if OP wants it deleted, they should be able to (without anyone re-creating it); I just want a way to coax them to do the opposite (and educate them about SO in the process).

Comment: @machineghost A very conservative take on that might be a special notification to be sent to the author of a self-deleted question when it gets its first undelete vote.

Comment: I think that's an excellent idea as well.  Probably better than mine actually, since  it requires less effort.  The only thing is I'd like to see some sort of indication that undeleting would do that; if it's just a "secret magic feature" then it wouldn't be nearly as effective.